# javascript enable disabled checkbox on click and select only one at a time

Tags: javascript, dynamic, checkbox, toggle

I am dynamically generating checkboxes with id like chkBox100 etc and with onClick function.

What I want to do is

1. Only select one checkbox at a time.
2. If a previous checkbox is checked and another checkbox is check, deslect the previous one.
3. If I click on the selected checkbox, it should deslect it.

I want to do it in standard javascript without jquery or any other library.

Please help your help will be appreciated. Here's my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title> New Document </title>  

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function toggle(chkBox)
      {
        if (chkBox.checked)
        {
          chkBox.checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
          chkBox.checked = true;
        }

        // only select one at a time.
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox100"  onClick="toggle(this);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox121"  onClick="toggle(this);">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1180" onClick="toggle(this);">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree with @gereeter. Maybe add a "None" option to deselect the other ones.

Comment: Also, form controls must have a name attribute, otherwise they can't be successful and won't be included when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using a library, I guess you could do the following and it seems to work if I understood you correctly.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/na8qL/)

Answer (score 2):

The code you are missing is the code that will deselect the rest. To do this, you should first get a list of all the check boxes, and deselect all of them. Then, select the one the user clicked on.

```
function toggle(chkBox) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementById("myForm").childNodes;
    var isChecked = chkBox.checked; //this just changed, so it really is whether the box wasn't checked beforehand.
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;  //clear all of them
    }
    if (isChecked) {
        chkBox.checked = true; //if the original one wasn't checked, check it
    }
}
```

An alternative to doing this is to use radio buttons, which automatically have the first two properties you want, but not the third, although you could fix this like RobG said, with another option saying "None of the above."

Comment: Except that if the checkbox was checked and the click unchecked it, then isChecked will be false and your code will re-check it (i.e. it will be impossible to uncheck the checkbox). The last line should just be 'chkBox.checked = isChecked;`. Incidentally, if isChecked is false, there should be no need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using radio buttons with a default checked button that is effectively the "no choice" option? No javascript required.

```
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="zero">Zero
<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="one">One
<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="two">Two
<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="None" checked>None of the above
```